# tentando compilar código

Tags: c#, webforms, visual-studio-2017

Boa tarde e boa noite pessoal.

Estou fazendo um projeto da faculdade em grupo e sabem que o melhor a fazer é jogar o código numa plataforma de hospedagem de código-fonte para todos trabalharem bem e no caso estamos usando o GitHub. Enfim, foi criado um Cadastro dentro do código que já esta no Git só que, quando eu puxo o código pra usar no Visual Studio acontece o que, eu compilo o código e insiro os dados quando eu salvo o cadastro ele volta ao Visual no Mapped com a seguinte informação:

Aparece essa linha no Mapped:

```
MySqlConnection conn = new 
MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["strConexao"]);
        conn.Open();
        return conn;
```

E essa mensagem no final da linha:

```
*MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: 'the host localhost does nor support 
 SSL connections.'
```

O que pode ser?

Comment: você poderia compartilhar o dado de host utilizado para conectar ao banco? O erro aponta que uma conexão localhost não suporta conexão SSL, provavelmente é só um engano nesse sentido.

Comment: Eu comecei um CRUD do zero, quero ver se é coisa da minha cabeça haha

Comment: Sem ver a string de conexão não tem como saber...

Answer (score 0):

Seu Host não suporta conexão por SSL, então tens que explicitar isso em sua connection string.
Para usar o mysql sem Ssl tens que colocar o parametro **SslMode=none** , igual o exemplo abaixo.
Pelo que vi no seu código essa alteração deve ser feita no seu **strConexao**.

```
Server=ip_servidor;Database=database_name;Uid=User_Name;Pwd=Password;SslMode=none;
```

Comment: Obrigado Carlos, foi isso mesmo que aconteceu.

Comment: de nada, poderias me positivar ? :)